# animate a highlighted link (animer un lien surligné)

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, transform, highlight

For some time, I try to reproduce the effect highlighted titles of link creation. 
http://www.platige.com/en/

But I can not reproduce this effect.
I wonder if it is possible to use this effect only in css3? or it is only possible in jquery?

I tested a few jquery but I can not have the desired effect.

I just ask for a little help. thank you !
I can not put my link fiddle ...;-(

`<p> <span class="lien"><a href="#">Titre</a></span></p>
<p> <span class="lien"><a href="#">Titre long long long long long long long</a></span></p>`

css

`.lien a {color: #585858; text-decoration: none; transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;}
.lien a:hover {background:#585858; color:#b4b4b4; padding:0 10px;}`

Comment: The link to the fiddle is missing.

Comment: If you can't include a link to your fiddle, please show your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/Czh8R/

HTML:

```
<a href=http://www.example.com>Link to an example page</a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdwnLpRPAAAAAxJREFUGFdj+M/AAAADAQEAYyRV0wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    background-size: 1% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: 0.5s all
}
a:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transition: 0.5s all
}
```

The `background-image` data uri is for a 1px light red image. I generated it with http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php An image must be used because the transition requires `background-size`. I did not vendor prefix the `transition`, so you will have to add `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc. accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much!
after a lot of tries, I tried something else. Thank you for your help this is exactly the desired effect!

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark my answer as "correct answer" for future users.

Comment: hello,

after a few tests I realized that it did not work in IE 10 ...
and for the text should be a mask or color inversion? should I go on jquery? and pluggin color? or is there another solution
thanks

Comment: `color` is the font color. If you specify a `color` under `a:hover`, it will fade to the 2nd color in 0.5s. jQuery is not needed for this. Not sure what you mean by "pluggin color."

Comment: hi,
yes I know how lol, http://jsfiddle.net/misscatas/shQF2/ but the effect is not good, it's just a opacity on the text. But if you look at the example, it is more of a color reversal or a mask and I talk about jquery because the effect does not work in ie

Comment: The original page's text color does not change. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/shQF2/1/

Comment: yes indeed you are right about the color change text ... ie but it still does not work? even
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; I tried ...
is there a solution?

Comment: IE10 is the first version of IE to support CSS transitions.